# Is there any way to record slow-motion video with swift?

Tags: swift, video, video-recording, slowmotion

If answer is yes, what are the frameworks can I use? I'm planning to do an app which records in slow-motion mode because in normal I just can record to max 60fps. Can I do it with swift or do I need to use objective-c? I would like to capture 240fps with slow-motion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get 1920x1080 240 fps in ultrawideanglecamera mode. And get that camera with discoverySession method of swift.